# Non-blockings reads/writes to stdin/stdout in C on Linux or Mac

Tags: nonblocking, stdio

I have two programs communicating via named pipes (on a Mac), but the buffer size of named pipes is too small. Program 1 writes 50K bytes to pipe 1 before reading pipe 2. Named pipes are 8K (on my system) so program 1 blocks until the data is consumed. Program 2 reads 20K bytes from pipe 1 and then writes 20K bytes to pipe2. Pipe2 can't hold 20K so program 2 now blocks. It will only be released when program 1 does its reads. But program 1 is blocked waiting for program 2. deadlock

I thought I could fix the problem by creating a gasket program that reads stdin non-blocking and writes stdout non-blocking, temporarily storing the data in a large buffer.  I tested the program using cat data | ./gasket 0 | ./gasket 1 > out, expecting out to be a copy of data.  However, while the first invocation of gasket works as expected, the read in the second program returns 0 before all the data is consumed and never returns anything other than 0 in follow on calls.

I tried the code below both on a MAC and Linux.  Both behave the same.  I've added logging so that I can see that the fread from the second invocation of gasket starts getting no data even though it has not read all the data written by the first invocation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 100000
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
int elements=0;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int total_read=0, total_write=0;
  FILE *logfile=fopen(argv[1],"w");

  int flags = fcntl(fileno(stdin), F_GETFL, 0);
  fcntl(fileno(stdin), F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
  flags = fcntl(fileno(stdout), F_GETFL, 0);
  fcntl(fileno(stdout), F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

  while (1) {
    int num_read=0;
    if (elements < (BUFFER_SIZE-1024)) { // space in buffer
      num_read = fread(&buffer[elements], sizeof(char), 1024, stdin);
      elements += num_read;
      total_read += num_read;
      fprintf(logfile,"read %d (%d) elements \n",num_read, total_read); fflush(logfile);
    }
    if (elements > 0) { // something in buffer that we can write
      int num_written = fwrite(&buffer[0],sizeof(char),elements, stdout); fflush(stdout);
      total_write += num_written;
      fprintf(logfile,"wrote %d (%d) elements \n",num_written, total_write); fflush(logfile);
      if (num_written > 0) { // copy data to top of buffer
        for (int i=0; i<(elements-num_written); i++) {
          buffer[i] = buffer[i+num_written];
        }
        elements -= num_written;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I guess I could make the gasket multi-threaded and use blocking reads in one thread and blocking writes in the other, but I would like to understand why non-blocking IO seems to break for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Dror.  How is "buffer size of named pipes is too small"?  In other words what is it not doing that you want it to do?

Comment: Hi.  I have two programs talking to each other via two named pipes.  Program 1 writes 50K bytes to pipe 1 before reading pipe 2.  Named pipes are 8K so program 1 blocks until the data is consumed.  Program 2 reads 20K bytes from pipe 1 and then writes 20K bytes to pipe2.   Pipe2 can't hold 20K so program 2 now blocks.  It will only be released when program 1 does its reads.  But program 1 is blocked waiting for program 2.  deadlock

Comment: OK Dror, my suggestion is to amend your question to explain that, and I will give you an answer for that.

Comment: Ok, question amended. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My general solution to any IPC project is to make the client and server non-blocking I/O.  To do so requires queuing data both on writing and reading, to handle cases where the OS can't read/write, or can only read/write a portion of your message.

The code below will probably seem like EXTREME overkill, but if you get it working, you can use it the rest of your career, whether for named pipes, sockets, network, you name it.

In pseudo-code:

```
typedef struct {
  const char* pcData, * pcToFree; // pcData may no longer point to malloc'd region
  int   iToSend;
} DataToSend_T;

queue of DataToSend_T qdts;

// Caller will use malloc() to allocate storage, and create the message in
// that buffer.  MyWrite() will free it now, or WritableCB() will free it
// later.  Either way, the app must NOT free it, and must not even refer to
// it again.

MyWrite( const char* pcData, int iToSend ) {
  iSent = 0;

  // Normally the OS will tell select() if the socket is writable, but if were hugely
  // compute-bound, then it won't have a chance to.  So let's call WritableCB() to
  // send anything in our queue that is now sendable.  We have to send the data in
  // order, of course, so can't send the new data until the entire queue is done.
  WritableCB();

  if ( qdts has no entries ) {
     iSent = write( pcData, iToSend );
      // TODO: check error
      // Did we send it all?  We're done.
      if ( iSent == iToSend ) {
          free( pcData );
          return;
      }
  }

  // OK, either 1) we had stuff queued already meaning we can't send, or 2)
  // we tried to send but couldn't send it all.
  add to queue qdts the DataToSend ( pcData + iSent, pcData, iToSend - iSent );
}



WritableCB() {
  while ( qdts has entries ) {
      DataToSend_T* pdts = qdts head;
      int iSent = write( pdts->cData, pdts->iToSend );
      // TODO: check error
      if ( iSent == pdts->iToSend ) {
          free( pdts->pcToFree );
          pop the front node off qdts
      else {
          pdts->pcData  += iSent;
          pdts->iToSend -= iSent;
          return;   
      }
  }
}



// Off-subject but I like a TINY buffer as an original value, that will always
// exercise the "buffer growth" code for almost all usage, so we're sure it works.
// If the initial buffer size is like 1M, and almost never grows, then the grow code
// may be buggy and we won't know until there's a crash years later.

int iBufSize = 1, iEnd = 0;  iEnd is the first byte NOT in a message
char* pcBuf = malloc( iBufSize );

ReadableCB() {
  // Keep reading the socket until there's no more data.  Grow buffer if necessary.
  while (1) {
      int iRead = read( pcBuf + iEnd, iBufSize - iEnd);
      // TODO: check error
      iEnd += iRead;

      // If we read less than we had space for, then read returned because this is
      // all the available data, not because the buffer was too small.
      if ( iRead < iBufSize - iEnd )
          break;

      // Otherwise, double the buffer and try reading some more.
      iBufSize *= 2;
      pcBuf = realloc( pcBuf, iBufSize );
  }

  iStart = 0;
  while (1) {
      if ( pcBuf[ iStart ] until iEnd-1 is less than a message ) {
          // If our partial message isn't at the front of the buffer move it there.
          if ( iStart ) {
              memmove( pcBuf, pcBuf + iStart, iEnd - iStart );
              iEnd -= iStart;
          }
          return;
      }
      // process a message, and advance iStart by the size of that message.
  }
}



main() {
  // Do your initial processing, and call MyWrite() to send and/or queue data.

  while (1) {
       select() // see man page
       if ( the file handle is readable )
           ReadableCB();
       if ( the file handle is writable )
           WritableCB();
       if ( the file handle is in error )
           // handle it;
       if ( application is finished )
           exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
  }
}
```